# HAProxy secondary algorithm for load balancing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, haproxy

I use the following config

```
balance url_param xyz check_post
hash-type consistent
```

because I was some requests based on xyz parameter to end up in the same server.
My question is what happens when a new request comes with a new value of xyz parameter. How is the next server selected?

The main problem I have is if are there any ways to specify the secondary/fallback algorithm to select the next server(i.e: the server with the least connection/load)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a round robin algorithm if you get a new request with a new value xyz.
As you are using the [URL_param algorithm](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.6-url_param), If no value is found or if the parameter is not found, then a round robin algorithm is applied.
The load balancing algorithm of a backend is set to round robin when no other algorithm, mode nor option have been set. The algorithm may only be set once for each backend.Please find this doc to [install HAProxy using round robin](https://blog.stackpath.com/load-balancing-haproxy/).

Example : balance roundrobin

Comment: My question is, is there a way to use any other algorithm instead of round-robin as fallback algorithm when new request arrives with new value of xzy. using `balance roundrobin` just defeats the purpose.

Comment: then you need to use a [query string parameter hash](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxys-load-balancing-algorithm-for-static-content-delivery-with-varnish/#hashing-the-whole-url-including-the-query-string) method. This might be helpful.

if that also does not suits then there is no other algorithm. 
You can refer to this [HAProxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html).

Comment: your answer does not address my problem. Thanks anyways :)